# PHP: Hebrew letters comparison

Tags: php, hebrew

I am trying to split Hebrew word into letters and get the index of a corresponding symbol. I have set the UTF-8 header and checked that the encoding of the files are actually UTF-8. But for some reason PHP is not able to make a correct comparison of the symbols and does not return a required symbol ID, while if I output the $text array it outputs it fine. I have an array of hebrew letters:

```
$id_symbols = array(
    280=>'א‬',
    281=>'בּ‬',
    282=>'ב‬',
    283=>'ג‬',
    284=>'ד‬',
    285=>'ה‬',
    286=>'ו‬',
    287=>'ז‬',
    288=>'ח‬',
    289=>'ט‬',
    290=>'י‬',
    291=>'כּ‬',
    292=>'כ‬',
    293=>'ךּ‬',
    294=>'ך‬',
    295=>'ל‬',
    296=>'מ‬',
    297=>'ם‬',
    298=>'נ‬',
    299=>'ן‬',
    300=>'ס‬',
    301=>'ע‬',
    302=>'פּ‬',
    303=>'פ‬',
    304=>'ף‬',
    305=>'צ‬',
    306=>'ץ‬',
    307=>'ק‬',
    308=>'ר‬',
    309=>'שׁ‬',
    310=>'שׂ‬',
    311=>'תּ‬',
    312=>'ת‬',
);
```

I send a post request to a page like this:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://pr.animizer.net/word-api.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "api_key=some_key&text=מילה&font=arial&font_size=30&fore_color=000000&back_color=FFFFFF&template=1,2,3&speed=4");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

exit($server_output);
```

Have received a POST request I am trying to get a key of each corresponding Hebrew letter:

```
function mb_str_split($string) {
$strlen = mb_strlen($string);
while ($strlen) {
    $array[] = mb_substr($string,0,1,"UTF-8");
    $string = mb_substr($string,1,$strlen,"UTF-8");
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
}
return $array;
}

$text = mb_str_split($_POST['text']); //splitting text into symbols

foreach($text as $t){

    foreach($id_symbols as $key=>$value){
        if($value == $t){
            $word[] = $key;
        }
    }

}



print_r($word);
```

and the output is

```
Array
(
)
```

P.S. Tried to output russian letters in the same way in the same files and they work fine. It doesn't look like the problem is the encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rei has pointed out in his answer, there is an issue with your current symbols array. After trimming the symbols, I noticed that the seven (7) values that had more than one character had a standard character and one of three *point* characters:

1. HEBREW POINT DAGESH OR MAPIQ (`&#1468;`)
2. HEBREW POINT SHIN DOT (`&#1473;`)
3. HEBREW POINT SIN DOT (`&#1474;`)

I wrote some code that converts the Hebrew characters into their decimal numerical HTML encoding values. If one of the *point* values is encountered, it combines with the next character in the array to match one of your symbols. The following code is working well for me:

```
<?php 

function _uniord($c) {
    if (ord($c{0}) >=0 && ord($c{0}) <= 127)
        return ord($c{0});
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 192 && ord($c{0}) <= 223)
        return (ord($c{0})-192)*64 + (ord($c{1})-128);
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 224 && ord($c{0}) <= 239)
        return (ord($c{0})-224)*4096 + (ord($c{1})-128)*64 + (ord($c{2})-128);
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 240 && ord($c{0}) <= 247)
        return (ord($c{0})-240)*262144 + (ord($c{1})-128)*4096 + (ord($c{2})-128)*64 + (ord($c{3})-128);
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 248 && ord($c{0}) <= 251)
        return (ord($c{0})-248)*16777216 + (ord($c{1})-128)*262144 + (ord($c{2})-128)*4096 + (ord($c{3})-128)*64 + (ord($c{4})-128);
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 252 && ord($c{0}) <= 253)
        return (ord($c{0})-252)*1073741824 + (ord($c{1})-128)*16777216 + (ord($c{2})-128)*262144 + (ord($c{3})-128)*4096 + (ord($c{4})-128)*64 + (ord($c{5})-128);
    if (ord($c{0}) >= 254 && ord($c{0}) <= 255)    //  error
        return FALSE;
    return 0;
}

function mb_str_split($string) {
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    while ($strlen) {
        $array[] = mb_substr($string,-1,1,"UTF-8");
        $string = mb_substr($string,0,$strlen-1,"UTF-8");
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    }
    return $array;
}

$hebrewText = $_POST['text'] //"מילה" used in example;

$text = mb_str_split($hebrewText); //splitting text into symbols

$word = [];

$lookupChrs = array(
    '1488'=>280,
    '14681489'=>281,
    '1489'=>282,
    '1490'=>283,
    '1491'=>284,
    '1492'=>285,
    '1493'=>286,
    '1494'=>287,
    '1495'=>288,
    '1496'=>289,
    '1497'=>290,
    '14681499'=>291,
    '1499'=>292,
    '14681498'=>293,
    '1498'=>294,
    '1500'=>295,
    '1502'=>296,
    '1501'=>297,
    '1504'=>298,
    '1503'=>299,
    '1505'=>300,
    '1506'=>301,
    '14681508'=>302,
    '1508'=>303,
    '1507'=>304,
    '1510'=>305,
    '1509'=>306,
    '1511'=>307,
    '1512'=>308,
    '14731513'=>309,
    '14741513'=>310,
    '14681514'=>311,
    '1514'=>312
    );

foreach($text as $t){
    $lookupChr = _uniord(array_shift($text));
    $lookupChr = (string)$lookupChr;
    //handle accents (two charactrers instead of one)
    if($lookupChr == "1468" || $lookupChr == "1473" || $lookupChr == "1474"){
        //accent detected, combine with next character
        //echo "\"" . $lookupChr . "\":\"" . _uniord(array_shift($text)) . "\"";
        $lookupChr .= _uniord(array_shift($text));
    }
    if($lookupChr != "0"){
        $word[] = $lookupChrs[$lookupChr];
    }
}

print_r($word);

//OUTPUT:
//    Array
//    (
//        [0] => 285
//        [1] => 295
//        [2] => 290
//        [3] => 296
//    )
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is the symbols array.

The final part of your code tries to match 1 symbol (character) to the elements in `$id_symbols`.
The problem is none of those elements are 1 symbol.
They are either 2 or 3 symbols each and therefore they will never match.

This code will show you.

```
foreach($id_symbols as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' '.$value.' '.json_encode($value)."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
280 א‬ "\u05d0\u202c"
281 בּ‬ "\u05d1\u05bc\u202c"
282 ב‬ "\u05d1\u202c"
283 ג‬ "\u05d2\u202c"
284 ד‬ "\u05d3\u202c"
285 ה‬ "\u05d4\u202c"
286 ו‬ "\u05d5\u202c"
287 ז‬ "\u05d6\u202c"
288 ח‬ "\u05d7\u202c"
289 ט‬ "\u05d8\u202c"
290 י‬ "\u05d9\u202c"
291 כּ‬ "\u05db\u05bc\u202c"
292 כ‬ "\u05db\u202c"
293 ךּ‬ "\u05da\u05bc\u202c"
294 ך‬ "\u05da\u202c"
295 ל‬ "\u05dc\u202c"
296 מ‬ "\u05de\u202c"
297 ם‬ "\u05dd\u202c"
298 נ‬ "\u05e0\u202c"
299 ן‬ "\u05df\u202c"
300 ס‬ "\u05e1\u202c"
301 ע‬ "\u05e2\u202c"
302 פּ‬ "\u05e4\u05bc\u202c"
303 פ‬ "\u05e4\u202c"
304 ף‬ "\u05e3\u202c"
305 צ‬ "\u05e6\u202c"
306 ץ‬ "\u05e5\u202c"
307 ק‬ "\u05e7\u202c"
308 ר‬ "\u05e8\u202c"
309 שׁ‬ "\u05e9\u05c1\u202c"
310 שׂ‬ "\u05e9\u05c2\u202c"
311 תּ‬ "\u05ea\u05bc\u202c"
312 ת‬ "\u05ea\u202c"
```

There should be only one backslash each but all of them have 2 or 3.

First problem, they are all terminated by `\u202c`.
The solution for this problem is easy: just remove them.

Second problem, even after removing all the `\u202c`, there are still 7 elements that are 2 symbols wide.
They are 281, 291, 293, 302, 309, 310, 311.
The solution for this problem: they must be replaced with their single symbol versions.

For instance, element of index 293 is `\u05da\u05bc` and it can be replaced with `\ufb3a`.
See https://codepoints.net/U+FB3A

I trust you can deal with the remaining 6 symbols.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped a lot